# Count by time in R

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series

This is our data:

[image]

The year arrange in real data is from 2010 to 2016.
Each accident id means a specific accident case.
I have a question: how to count the accident numbers by time? That is how to figure out the number of accidents happened in one day?
Besides, the time is separated into four columns. So, need I use the group function in dplyr package? Or need I transform those columns back to one column in date type? If so, what can I do after that?

Any suggestions will be a great help!!! Thank you in advance:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly can use dplyr for this.

```
library(dplyr)

acc <- data.frame(
  acc_id=1:9,
  year=16,
  month=c(2, 3, 7, 8, 12, 12, 5, 5, 9),
  day=c(1, 16, 13, 15, 23, 23, 1, 14, 23),
  hrmn=c(1445, 1800, 1900, 1930, 1100, 1115, 1145, 1915, 1900)
)

acc %>% group_by(year, month, day) %>% summarize(num_accidents=n())
```

Returns:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 4
# Groups:   year, month [?]
   year month   day num_accidents
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>         <int>
1    16     2     1             1
2    16     3    16             1
3    16     5     1             1
4    16     5    14             1
5    16     7    13             1
6    16     8    15             1
7    16     9    23             1
8    16    12    23             2
```

There may be other things you do that would make it worthwhile creating a proper datetime out of the separate columns but for simple aggregations like this the split seems fine.

Comment: That works well!!!! Thanks a lot for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do that using the `ddply` function in the `plyr` package, like this:

```
library(plyr)

counts <- ddply(df, .(df$year, df$month, df$day), nrow)
names(counts) <- c("year", "month", 'day', "Acc_count")
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for your answer and the edit of this question!